# How to spatially plot an attribute parameter?

Tags: spatial, fill

Here is my code below. I want to plot CO2 distribution over the South African map.

Loading packages

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw())
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
```

Assigning world to the countries of the world data

```
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
```

Reading the local file with CO2 and geographic coordinates (Lon and Lat)

```
SA_CO2 <- read_csv2("C:/Users/Xolile Ncipha/Documents/SA_CO2_DJF_2004_2009.csv")
```

Converting the data frame to a sf object and the coordinate reference system projection to WGS84, which is the CRS code #4326.

```
(SA_CO2 <- st_as_sf(SA_CO2, coords = c("Lon", "Lat"), crs = 4326, agr = "constant"))
```

Plotting the map and overlaying it with CO2 data[The output of my code/script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crqxM.png).

```
ggplot(data = world) + geom_sf() + geom_sf(data = SA_CO2, aes(fill = CO2)) +
```

CO2 legend

```
scale_fill_gradientn(colors = sf.colors(10)) +
```

Confining the map to South African domain.

```
coord_sf(xlim = c(15, 35), ylim = c(-36, -22.3), expand = FALSE) +
```

Axis labels

```
xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")
```

The results is the geographic points on the map. I don't get the overlay of CO2 data and its spatial distribution. I have attached a picture of the resulting map and the spatial data.

Comment: Dear Hoppo, Thanks for your helpful response. Sorry I did not include the data file.  I have included a link to the data file (https://www.dropbox.com/s/g648u16rszjnnu1/SA_CO2_DJF_2004_2009.csv?dl=0) and names of the relevant towns in SA (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezingxbfq0x0m5w/Town_Names.csv?dl=0). I'm seeking to do a spatial distribution of ambient CO2 data of densely spatially placed data. Could you please also help me with adding the code for including the names of the towns on the map. I hope the supporting info I provided will be helpful for your appreciated help. Xolile

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question.  But, unfortunately, you did not provide a link to the source of your data ( "SA_CO2_DJF_2004_2009.csv"), so it was necessary for me to create some data that is likely somewhat similar to your data, but probably not exactly the same.

I found a spelling error in the following line of your code.  Even after correcting the spelling error, this line of code continued causing an error.

```
scale_fill_gradientn(colors = sf.colors(10)) +
```

The data I used included tons of CO2 from SA during the years, 2010-2016.  I also  selected a few SA cities with populations from another source, and then allocated the SA annual CO2 by the ratio of the combined city populations.  Therefore, those cities with smaller populations were allocated smaller proportions of the annual CO2 and the larger cities were allocated larger ratio's of CO2.

```
https://howsouthafrica.com/major-cities-international-airports-south-africa/
https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/EN.ATM.CO2E.KT?locations=ZA&view=map
```

The code used to create the plot shown at the link below is:

```
ggplot(data = world) + 
    geom_sf() + 
    geom_sf(data = coor.sf, aes(size = tons), 
    fill = "blue", color = "blue", alpha = .3) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(15, 35), ylim = c(-36, -22.3), 
    expand = FALSE) + xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")
```

Please email me if you have any questions.

[[[![SA CO2]]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ukOV.png)

Comment: Dear Gray, Thanks for your helpful response. Sorry I did not include the data file.  I have included a link to the data file (https://www.dropbox.com/s/g648u16rszjnnu1/SA_CO2_DJF_2004_2009.csv?dl=0) and names of the relevant towns in SA (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezingxbfq0x0m5w/Town_Names.csv?dl=0). I'm seeking to do a spatial distribution of ambient CO2 data of densely spatially placed data. Could you please also help me with adding the code for including the names of the towns on the map. I hope the supporting info I provided will be helpful for your appreciated help. Xolile

Comment: Hi, I looked over your datasets and I do not understand some of the information.   I don't recognize the Lat/Lon values, and I don't understand the why there is a number in the TownName column.

Comment: Hi Gray, I'm sorry for the messed up columns in the csv files. Somehow the dropbox messed up with the csv files columns. I did not realize this as I did not open them after saving them in dropbox. I checked the linked files now, the csv CO2 data file columns are somehow still semicolon separated (https://www.dropbox.com/s/6bi77woa6vzjz96/SA_CO2_DJF_2004_2009_1.csv?dl=0), however in xlsx files the columns look fine (https://www.dropbox.com/s/7yld0m3i0ldu8j6/SA_CO2_DJF_2004_2009_1.xlsx?dl=0), (https://www.dropbox.com/s/nuib2spp8fwomkw/Town_Names_1.xlsx?dl=0). Thanks so much for your patience.